# Attempting to use Segoe font in browser

Tags: css, windows-7, fonts, firefox3.5

I want to render a page with fonts mostly being `font-family:"Segoe"` (that line goes in the appropriate class selectors which I've verified are working), however I get back a standard font (times new roman I think). Why won't it work? I am on Windows-7 64 bit so it's installed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name is "Segoe UI" not "Segoe". Change that and it will work.

Comment: Hmm. I was under the impression that you didn't specify the specific font, but i'll try it :)